# Multiple conditional selector with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Let's say I have the following running script: (http://jsfiddle.net/raidnet/AcuU3/ )

JS

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function (event, data) {
  $(".group2").hide();
  $('#flip2').on('change', function () {
    var regtype = $("#flip2").val();
    if (regtype == "0") {
        $(".group2").hide();
    } else {
        $(".group2").show();
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
 <!-- group A -->
 <li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="flip2">FLIP 2 Label:</label>
    <select name="flip2" id="flip2" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
        <option value="0">NO</option>
        <option value="1">SI</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li data-role="fieldcontain" class="group2">
    <label for="name2" class="ui-hidden-accessible group2">FLIP 2A</label>
    <input type="text" class="group2" name="name2" placeholder="FLIP 2A" id="name2" data-mini="true" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
</li>
<!-- group B -->
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="flip3">FLIP 3 Label:</label>
    <select name="flip3" id="flip3" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
        <option value="0">NO</option>
        <option value="1">SI</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li data-role="fieldcontain" class="group3">
    <label for="name3" class="ui-hidden-accessible group3">FLIP 3A</label>
    <input type="text" class="group3" name="name3" placeholder="FLIP 3A" id="name3" data-mini="true" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
    </ li>
    <!-- group H -->
    </ ul>
```

This script works fine for 1 select element, but if I have more the one groups of select + input elements let's says 10, how could I enhance the java script?
How could I pass the id from the selected fields to the script?

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AcuU3/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

Based on your comment, to go through pre-selected switches and hide the ones with "0" value.

```
$('select').each(function () {
  if($(this).val() == 0) {
    $(this).closest('li').next().hide();
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ek3Ne/)**

---

DOM elements are enhanced by jQM and render them in a different way that raw HTML code. Hence, you need to know the structure/hierarchy after enhancement.

For example, slider HTML code

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="flip2">FLIP 2 Label:</label>
  <select name="flip2" id="flip2" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
    <option value="0">NO</option>
    <option value="1">SI</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

After enhancement, it will look like

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c ui-first-child">
  <label for="flip2" id="flip2-label" class="ui-slider">FLIP 2 Label:</label>
  <select name="flip2" id="flip2" data-role="slider" data-mini="true" class="ui-slider-switch">
    <option value="0">NO</option>
    <option value="1">SI</option>
  </select>
  <div role="application" class="ui-slider ui-slider-switch ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini"><span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 100%;">SI</span><span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-b ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 0%;">NO</span>
    <div class="ui-slider-inneroffset"><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-slider-handle-snapping ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuetext="SI" title="SI" aria-labelledby="flip2-label" style="left: 100%;"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

To answer your question, you can do this

```
$('.ui-input-text').closest('li').hide();
$('select').on('change', function () {
  var regtype = $(this).val();
  if (regtype == "0") {
    $(this).closest('li').next().hide();
  } else {
    $(this).closest('li').next().show();
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cq8ag/)**

Comment: Runs fine only if all initial value are equal 0. We needs some enhancement to hide only the fields with initial value equal 0.

Answer (score 1):

javascript:

```
    $(document).bind("pageinit", function (event, data) {
    $("li[class^=group]").hide();
    $('select').on('change', function () {
        var regtype = $(this).val();
        var index = this.id.match(/\d/g)[0]
        if (regtype == "0") {
            $("li.group" + index).hide();
        } else {
            $("li.group" + index).show();
        }
    });
 });
```

basically what this is doing is adding a click event to every `<select>` and then getting the corresponding `<li>` by using the group class and appending the index for the `<select>` element. so when you change `flip2` the code will get a `<li>` with a class called `group2`

Comment: Runs fine only if all initial value are equal 0. We needs some enhancement to hide only the fields with initial value equal 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, using [attribute startswith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function (event, data) {
    $("li[class^='group']").hide();
    $('select[id^="flip"]').on('change', function () {
        $(this).closest('li').next().toggle(); //get the closest li and get to the next element and do a toggle, which toggles the visibility
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNGGB/)**

But ideally you can use a common class for these,  and just do

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function (event, data) {
    $(".group").hide();
    $('.flip').on('change', function () {
        $(this).closest('li').next().toggle();//get the closest li and get to the next element and do a toggle, which toggles the visibility
    });
});
```

*Since the flip has only 2 possible values and you need to toggle the states, you can get rid of the if condition and just toggle everytime.*

Comment: Runs fine only if all initial value are equal 0. We needs some enhancement to hide only the fields with initial value equal 0.